# How can I disable Outlook without deleting and reinstalling, to forestall customs officers' seeing emails?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

My MS Outlook contains emails that can be accessed even when offline, much less  automatically updates my email when connected to any Internet.

Please recommend a  method more efficient than deleting Outlook before I cross a border, and reinstalling Outlook afterwards, every time that I travel?

Comment: You do the same thing you should do to prevent anyone from looking at your stuff. Encrypt the hard drive and use a strong password.

Comment: US and other customs offices have the right to impound devices and/or demand passwords.

Comment: You can disable your user, and have a fake user enabled, this way the real user isn’t even displayed in the list of users.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use your PC for sensitive work. Keep an OS on a cheap thumb drive or HD card and destroy it before going through POE. That also helps prevent [spyware](https://www.entrepreneur.com/article/223433) being installed.

Though you can encrypt storage media, whether the HDD or external, some countries can [legally demand your password](https://gsl-consulting.blog/2018/10/05/customs-can-demand-password/) and/or confiscate a device. See [Wired](https://www.wired.com/2017/02/guide-getting-past-customs-digital-privacy-intact/) for more information.

Comment: Outlook allows you to store .PST in any location you want, you could store .PST on a drive that is encrypted, and this would prevent access to those emails.  Automatically updating can be solved by not storing your password.

Answer (score 0):

A password can be set for an Outlook Data File (.pst) to help prevent unintentional intrusion by other people who share your computer. When a password is used, a password prompt appears when Outlook starts or when the file is first opened within an Outlook session.

However, Outlook Data File (.pst) passwords aren't intended to provide security against intentional malicious attempts to access your information. For a better way to restrict access to your data, create a password-protected Windows user account for any person who uses the computer.

Reference: [Set a password to help protect your Outlook information](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/set-a-password-to-help-protect-your-outlook-information-f60fb0e7-f0ad-4d7c-858b-9619d1b9f0b6)